# The partial sums of $\log n$

Tags: summation, analytic-number-theory

I know that $$\sum_{n\leq x}\log(n)=x\log(x)-x+O(\log(x))$$
but I read (in a proof of a theorem ) the following formula $$\sum_{n\leq x}\log(n)=x\log(x)+O(x)$$
Why are the two forms equal?

Comment: Because $$-x+O(\log x)=O(x).$$

Comment: The error term $O(x)$ is less specific than $O(\log x)$.

Comment: Any $\mathcal{O}(\log x)$ function is also $\mathcal{O}(x)$ because $x$ grows faster than $\log x$. $-x$ is obviously $\mathcal{O}(x)$, so their sum is also $\mathcal{O}(x)$.

Comment: That first expression gives more information than the second.

Comment: Thank you all for the clarification!